# How do i disable Node's/npm Intellisense on VSCode for certain workspaces?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, javascript-intellisense

I installed Nodejs & `npm` and made a little script.

The problem I'm having now, is that I'm getting auto-complete options for Nodejs imports and I don't want `nodejs` to kick in.

Is there a way to disable these autocomplete options for projects where I'm not planning on using Nodejs/npm libraries?

For example: I write "console", VSCode gives me the option to add `const Console = require("console")`
[image: autocomplete when writing "console"]

Another example: I write "cons", VSCode gives me way more autocomplete options for other imports(/requires) that I don't care about right now...
[image: autocomplete when writing "cons"]